# Qgis2threejs "disk object"

Tags: qgis2threejs

First of all, I'm completely new to qgis2threejs.

During a field trip I've measured strike/dip for some cracks in the bedrock and mapped the positions, and now I'm trying to show the results as a disk with the strike and dip for each point.

My data looks something like this (added as a delimited layer):

Point, Strike, Dip, Point, Easting, Northing, Height

1, 220, 30 NE, 1, 392430, 7302787, 9.2
...
...

When selecting "Object Type: Disk" for the point layer I can apparently choose the column with the "Dip" and "Dip direction", but there is only 4 possibilities: Fixed value, "Easting", "Northing", "Height"

Is something wrong with my data format? How do I get to choose the "Dip"-column for the dip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dip column is not a number. Remove the 'NE' and other text from the data and it should appear as a selectable column.